# How Oracle SQL resolve qualified names in join condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you explain me or even point the Oracle SQL documentation where can I find explanation for the following question:

Consider the following query which runs fine:

```
Select * from DUAL join DUAL on DUAL.DUMMY='X';
```

I would expect Oracle to say 'Ambiguous Table reference' (or something like that), but it executes fine returning one row with two columns. Any ideas why? moreover, removing a column qualification will cause 'Column Ambiguously defined' error.

I run queries using Oracle SQL v. 12.1

Comment: I think you have to check SQL-92 Standard. 
Paragraph 6.4  <column reference>. (3.a.ii.1)
In your case `daul.dummy`is taken from second table.

Comment: I just tried that on Oracle 11.2 and got the "column ambiguously defined" error. Besides that the DUAL table is some kind of magic: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388

Comment: I tried the same with other table and result was the same. I used DUAL as an example of table with well-known structure

Answer (score 2):

There is many special cases in Oracle. In this case the latter definition overrides the first one. Like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 2 VAL FROM DUAL) DUAL JOIN (SELECT 1 VAL FROM DUAL) DUAL ON DUAL.VAL = 2
```

doesn't return any row.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 2 VAL FROM DUAL) DUAL JOIN (SELECT 1 VAL FROM DUAL) DUAL ON DUAL.VAL = 1
```

returns one.

You can do the same thing with factored subqueries, but in this case the latter definition does not override the first one:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT 1 X FROM DUAL),
T AS (SELECT 2 X FROM DUAL)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    T
```

returns 1.

But I strongly recommend not rely on these behaviors and use unique object qualifications.